# Socket Not Connecting in Android : Getting error code "400" and error message "XHR Poll error"

Tags: android, sockets, socket.io

I am trying to connect to socket from my Android App. I was able to connect to it fine but after some time the socket suddenly stopped connecting and i cant understand why it stopped connecting all of a suddent, it was working before.

I have been trying to debug it for hours but not sure what the problem is.

I logged the error. Here it is:

```js
[{
  "cause": {
    "detailMessage": "400",
    "stackTrace": [],
    "suppressedExceptions": []
  },
  "detailMessage": "xhr poll error",
  "stackTrace": [],
  "suppressedExceptions": []
}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. It had to do something with the Socket version.

Try switching from `1.0.0` to `2.0.0` or vice versa if you're facing some problem.